# TYPO3: Redirect url with ID to speaking url

Tags: redirect, typo3, realurl

Is there a possibility to redirect an url with an ID (e.g. index.php?id=123) to the speaking url?
The speaking url was generated by ext. realurl. realurl itself doesn't do the redirect.
There's an extension for older TYPO3 versions (https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/forcerealurls2/).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the extension forcerealurls either via https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/forcerealurls/ or https://github.com/sorenmalling/typo3-forcerealurls

Comment: This extension is from 2008 and uses e.g. `t3lib_div::getIndpEnv`, is this extension really working in newer TYPO3 versions? Extension "forcerealurls2", which is based on "forcerealurls", seems to be better.

Comment: Both extensions (forcerealurls and forcerealurls2) will not work with TYPO3 CMS 8 or later.

Comment: For the greater good, submit a PR and I will take care of updating them both on TER and packagist. Alternative, copy the code directly to your sitepackage